# getElementby ID not returning value VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, getelementbyid

I have searched SO and haven't been able to get an answer but I think I am close.  I am new to coding so I appreciate the help.

I use Hubspot manage customer details and excel to produce quotes.  I want to scrape customer data from Hubspot and have it populate the quote.

The HTML code

```
<input type="text" property="PropertyRecord { &quot;calculated&quot;: false, 
;createdUserId&quot;: null, &quot;defaultValue&quot;: undefined, 
;deleted&quot;: null, &quot;description&quot;: &quot;A contact's first 
name&quot;, &quot;displayMode&quot;: &quot;current_value&quot;, 
;displayOrder&quot;: 0, &quot;externalOptions&quot;: false, 
;favorited&quot;: true, &quot;favoritedOrder&quot;: 0, 
;fieldType&quot;: &quot;text&quot;, &quot;filterName&quot;: 
&quot;&quot;, &quot;formField&quot;: true, &quot;groupName&quot;: 
;contactinformation&quot;, &quot;hidden&quot;: false, 
;hubspotDefined&quot;: true, &quot;label&quot;: &quot;First Name&quot;, 
;mutableDefinitionNotDeletable&quot;: true, &quot;name&quot;: 
;firstname&quot;, &quot;numberDisplayHint&quot;: null, 
;objectType&quot;: undefined, &quot;options&quot;: List [], 
;optionsAreMutable&quot;: null, &quot;placeholder&quot;: &quot;&quot;, 
;prospectType&quot;: null, &quot;readOnlyDefinition&quot;: true, 
;readOnlyValue&quot;: false, &quot;referencedObjectType&quot;: null, 
;searchable&quot;: true, &quot;showCurrencySymbol&quot;: null, 
;sortable&quot;: true, &quot;textDisplayHint&quot;: null, 
;type&quot;: &quot;string&quot;, &quot;updatedUserId&quot;: null }" 
value="Jonnevie" id="uid-ctrl-54" data-field="firstname" data-selenium-
test="property-input-firstname" autocomplete="off" class="form-control 
private-form__control private-form__control--inline isInline">
```

I am using the following code to scrape and getting a `Run Rime Error 424`

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim ieDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim firstname As Object
Dim url As Variant
Dim ID As Variant
Dim Content As String
Dim i As Integer

Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

ieApp.Visible = 1

url = "https://app.hubspot.com/sales/3425759/contact/379701/?interaction=note"
ieApp.navigate url

Do While ieApp.Busy:
DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Dim ele As Object
Set ieDoc = ieApp.document

For Each ele In ieDoc.getElementById("uid-ctrl-8")

Debug.Print (ele.text)

Next ele

   ieApp.Quit
```

What would be a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: On what line is the error and you have ctrl-8 in the HTML but ctrl-4 in VBA in which case you should have Set firstname = ieDoc.getElementById("uid-ctrl-8")

Comment: And this line Dim url, id, content .... only content is String the first two are variants. Declare Dim url As String, id As String, content As String.

Comment: I made the change to the code and updated it.  Error 424 - Object required coming up on set firstname line.  Any ideas Thans

Comment: What if you try `Dim ele as Object`, then `For each ele in ieDoc.getElementById("uid-ctrl-8") // debug.print(ele.textContent) // next ele` ...does that throw an error? (Or just `debug.print(ele.text)`)

Comment: Its still throwing the same error.  Maybe the HTML code isnt as straight forward as I thought.  I have updated the full instance

Comment: `getElementById` returns a single Element. `Set ele = ieDoc.getElementById("uid-ctrl-8")` and `Debug.Print ele.value`

Comment: If the above html elements are taken into consideration, what is your expected output from that?

Comment: I am trying to return value="Jonnevie" which I believe corresponds to the ID

Comment: The error is occuring at ieDoc.getElementById("uid-ctrl-8")

Comment: did you try @Slai's suggestion?

Comment: I tried both of Slai's suggestions.  Both error at the same point.  The ID name keeps chaning numbers too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below approach. You can't use `.getElementById()` in a for loop as you did above. The ID contains a single element. However, I used `.querySelector()` to do the trick cause the ID's are not static and you can't use it in a for loop either.

```
Set firstname = ieDoc.querySelector("[id^='uid-ctrl-']")
MsgBox firstname.getAttribute("value")
```

Comment: SIM, you are a gun!  Thank you very much.  It worked a treat.   With a dynamic ID, what do you think is the best way to query customer details: first name, last name, email etc?

Comment: Im thinking the data-field could be an option

Comment: Without seeing the relevant elements in which expected data remain, It's hard to tell you in advance which way you should go. However if it is `data-field` which contains the item you are after then you can go like this: `Set firstname = ieDoc.querySelector("[id^='uid-ctrl-']")
    Debug.Print firstname.getAttribute("data-field")
    Debug.Print firstname.getAttribute("value")` and so on.

Comment: Btw, If it solves the issue, make sure to tick the grayed out checkmark next to my answer to accept it as a solution. Thanks.

Comment: As an FYI for those using this code, I needed to add a further delay in addition to the ready state.  IE.quit and IE = nothing was moved up the order to prevent multiple instances opening.

Comment: Nice, I didn't notice that the id changes. @Pilchy `.querySelector('[data-field=firstname]').value` seems to work too.